# Erro R "Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Tags: r, r-markdown

When starting RStudio, this error appears. I can run several commands, but I can't compile anything in Rmarkdown. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

The error does not appear when typing a path to read from the file. It even appears when I try to compile an empty file in RMarkdown.

The error even appears with the default example script in RMarkdown.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Autor"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: It sounds as though you have a startup script (`.Rprofile` or similar) that lists a filename starting out `"C:\U..."`.  You need to double backslashes in R strings, i.e. it should be `"C:\\U..."`.

Comment: You can also change all directory-separating backslashes with forward-slashes and skip this. For instance, `"C:\\Users\\Antonio\\R"` works the same as `"C:/Users/Antonio/R"`, and in my opinion the latter is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330. I used the command file.edit(".Rprofile") and cleaned the commands that appeared. It started working normally again.